# Clicking Delete button redirects to Loging page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, begincollectionitem

I am using [BeginCollectionItem](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) to dynamically add items to a list.  If I attempt click a newly added row, the app immediately halts and redirects me to the login page.  If I delete an item that already existed, it deletes it from the database, then deletes it from the UI, then redirects me to the login page.  If the item is newly added, it does not even run the code in the delete.onClick at all the other does, but they both end up with redirecting me to the login screen.

I had a similar problem when trying append the div and was told to add:

```
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

I tried that but it did not stop my app from halting and redirecting to the login page.  Here is my delete code:

```
    $("a.deleteRow").on("click", function (e) {

    var container = $(this).closest('.editorRow');
    var id = container.data('id');
    var $t = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Delete","Request", new { area = "" })",
            data: { CommentId: id },
            success: function (e) {
                $t.parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        })

    return false;
});
```

Here is the partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Comments"))
{
        <div class="row editorRow" data-id="@Model.Id" style="padding-bottom:10px">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)

            <div class="col-xl-2">
                @if (Model.CreatorName == "" || Model.CreatorName == null)
                {
                    Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CreatorName, (string)@ViewBag.UserName);
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CreatorName)

                }
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-8">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Comment, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2">
                <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

here is Delete code in Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Delete(int CommentId)
    {
        service.DeleteComment(CommentId);
        return Content("" + CommentId);

    }
```

> Update:

After putting the delete code in document.ready, the ajax portion deleting the existing row now works fine.  However, attempting to add and delete a row without first saving that row is still redirecting.  The new delete code which now works with an "existing" row is as follows:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.deleteRow").on("click", function (e) {

        var container = $(this).closest('.editorRow');
        var id = container.data('id');
        var $t = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Delete","Request", new { area = "" })",
            data: { CommentId: id },
            success: function (e) {
                $t.parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
                return false;
            }
        })

        return false;
    });
});
```

I am new to jQuery and am trying to understand as well as get my project working.

Comment: I think redirection to the login page is not related to your jquery code. check your backend and Authentication method.

Comment: @Mahdi Farhani, I'm pretty sure it has to do with jQuery as before.  I moved the code into $(document).ready(function(){}) and now the posting code that posts an existing line item works fine, now it is just the newly added div. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There is not a client-side redirection in your code (at least in this code), so maybe you have another code that not shown in this question, or as I told you your server-side code redirects the request to the login page.

Comment: Also, maybe an exception occurred which is handled by your configuration, and the login page shows.

Comment: @Mahdi Farhani, as I said, I had "append" code previously that was redirecting to login because I hadn't included the stoppropogation code, and now this is partially working just because I moved it into document.ready.  I have NOTHING in my ActionResult that directs back to the login page.  That is something it does on an error.  However, because it will not step through the jQuery delete code, I can't tell what the problem is.

Comment: @Mahdi Farhani, perhaps there is an exception but I turned on break on ALL exceptions in Visual Studio, so if there is an exception in Visual Studio, it is not catching it.

Comment: This means you have an exception in your code, use try-catch in your code in return an appropriate message to your client

Comment: I highly recommended you to use try-catch in your action

Comment: @Mahdi Farhani - my  service.DeleteComment(CommentId) uses try/catch so that I don't need it in the Controller.

Comment: Can you trace your code? set a breakpoint on your delete code and step-in and watch what happining.

Comment: @Mahdi Farhani, like I said, I cannot step through the delete function in the jQuery on a new record because it redirects as soon as I click the button.  If it was an "existing" record that was rendered with the "foreach"  I can step through both the delete jQuery code and the C# code, but if I click the "Add Comment" button to add a new div and then click delete, it does not step through the code and just redirects to login.

Comment: Let's test it in another way. first set e.preventDefault at the first line in your function ( before var container). and would you please send the created HTML of your code (Html.BeginCollectionItem.....) I wanna see there is any Form tag on your page that would redirect you in the login page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225709/discussion-between-rani-radcliff-and-mahdi-farhani).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code I cannot see that this redirection is related to jquery. Can you take a look at the RequestController and Delete action. Most likely your Delete Action in controller is doing the redirection in this case after it has deleted the record from database.